# Error estimate of polynomial quadratures missing some terms

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, interpolation

Normally, for trapezoid rule and simpson's rule, etc, error analysis is done by using the error formula for interpolation. However, if the polynomial is restricted to some terms, for example, a quadrature of $ax^{3}+bx$ (simpson's 3/8 rule with two terms set to $0$), that method no longer applies. And this quadrature does not behave uniformly, since the error is very large at $0$. The question is, what method should I use to derive the error of such a quadrature?

Comment: Can you please show how $ax^3 + bx$ is related to 3/8 rule with two terms set to zero? What interval $x \in [A,B]$ are you using?

Comment: @uranix I was just trying to make an analogue, because the 3/8 rule uses a 3 degree polynomial and this one does too. $ax^{3}+bx$ actually uses only two points. And the interval is "arbitrary interval" $(m,n)$. Thanks